# Ubuntu Server Headless Installation to SSH

Tags: server, system-installation, ssh, headless

I want to install Ubuntu Server via SSH. I am new to this, so I want to see the installation prompts to guide me through the install. So I want to get the SSH service running and then have the rest of the installation prompts come up from there.

I have come across two answers.

- https://askubuntu.com/a/917176/158442

  This answer shows how to create a bootable USB that I can SSH into. I don't see how I would do the install for Ubuntu Server on the primary drive through this USB disk.
- https://zameermanji.com/blog/2021/9/9/installing-ubuntu-20-04-over-ssh/#conclusion
  This talks about using NoCloud to get SSH setup and running automatically. I just don't know where or how to generate the user-data file that is needed.

Comment: Installing Ubuntu Server to headless hardware can be done using the process at https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/automated-server-installation/16612